# Add each variable of a Query String to an array

Tags: php, sql

I have here the following output in a Query String:
`add_to_cart.php?product_id=4&product_name=Pizza&quantity=1&additional_id[]=1&additional_quantity[]=3&additional_id[]=4&additional_quantity[]=5`
I'm trying to set up an array with each of additional IDs and their respective quantities. Each ID corresponds to an additional product in the database in the table *additionals*, and I need to make a SQL query for each ID to get the price and the name of the additional and then show the price multiplicated with their quantity.
If I use:

```
foreach ($_GET['additional_id'] as $value)
{
    echo "<p>{$value}</p>";
}
```

If the output is based in the example Query String above I get:
    `1`
    `4`
But I need to add each ID with their quantity inside of this array in the file **add_to_cart.php**:

```
$columns = array
(
    'product_id_session' => $product_id_session,
    'product_id' => $product_id,
    'product_name' => $product_name,
    'product_price' => $product_price,
    'quantity' => $quantity,
    'additional_id' => //Maybe I need a foreach here or another array to add all the additionals of Query String?
    'additional_quantity' => //Here too?
    'additional_name' => //Retrieved from database, like price below
    'additional_price' => //Like additional_name, I will need to connect to database and get the price of each additional ID present in the Query String
);
```

I was trying to do something like:
`add_to_cart.php?product_id=4&product_name=Pizza&quantity=1&additionals=additional_id[]=1&additional_quantity[]=3&additional_id[]=4&additional_quantity[]=5`
This can be the right way? Maybe I can create an array with `additionals` and parse it to the `columns` array? And how to get the `additional_price` and `additional_name` for each additional ID present in Query String by a SQL connection to the table `additionals`? This is being very complicated for me. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Why are you using $_GET instead of $_POST?  Generally, $_GET is better used for bookmarking, and $_POST is better for passing data.

Comment: @SableFoste It was just to illustrate the output. My problem is being to pass it all to an array and then be able to use each of its variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foreach ($_GET['additional_id'] as $key=>$value)
{
    $id = htmlspecialchars($value);
    $qty = htmlspecialchars($_GET['additional_quantity'][$key]);
    echo "<p>ID: $id, Quantity: $qty</p>";
}
```

This assumes that the `additional_id` and `additional_quantity` arrays are of the same length and each index of `additional_id` matches the same index of `additional_quantity`.

You should probably be using another method to pass these sorts of values though. Doing it this way is really insecure and brittle.

Comment: Nice, I think this is the right way. My biggest problem is to compare each `additional_id` in database to get their price and name and then add these values in the array `columns`.